# how to cancel an ajax request and clear info while it is running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

this is the piece of the code I have. By default, "ajax_info_box" is hidden, by clicking "button", "ajax_info_box" shows and sends request, it probably takes about 5 seconds to result. How do I cancel and clear the request by click “cancel"? Any help would be appreciated.

```
   $('.ajax_info_box').hide()
   $('.button').click(function() {
   $('.ajax_info_box').show()
    var xhr =  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          do something here

    });
    $('.cancel').click(function () {
       suppose to kill the request here
       $('.ajax_info_box').hide()
    }); 
});
```

Comment: even if you abort the request... the server side processing will continue to execute

Answer (score 2):

xhr has an abort method on it

```
xhr.abort()
```

More here [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work for me since I am using jquery 1.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('.ajax_info_box').hide()
   $('.button').click(function() {
   $('.ajax_info_box').show()
    var xhr =  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          do something here

    });
    $('.cancel').click(function () {
       xhr.abort();
       $('.ajax_info_box').hide()
    }); 
});
```